# How am I able to animate a spritesheet using CSS when the sprites aren't uniform?

Tags: css, html

I went through almost my entire spritesheet without problem. Everything was uniform. I got to the last few monsters that have varying widths and ran into the problem of being able to see the monster to the left of it. Is there a way to hide the overflow or do I need to change my spritesheet to account for non-uniformity?

```css
.monster {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/423540996098228245/494950824963866635/16x16.png");
}

.dragon {
  width: 113px;
  height: 90px;
  animation: dragon .8s steps(2) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dragon {
  from {
    background-position: -7885px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -8115px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="monster dragon"></div>
```

Comment: I would certainly aim to have every frame of a single animation use the same size. You could possibly work around it, but the extra effort required to programatically hide/add extra space is far greater than the effort to add some blank space to your spritesheet.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I used a sprite compiler online. I guess just simply increasing the padding? Also, if you don't mind answering - is this the best method to animation? @DBS

Answer (score 0):

I would put the size and the position in the "keyframes" itself because it lets you more control at the dynamic picture. look at the next code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.monster {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/423540996098228245/494950824963866635/16x16.png");
}

.dragon {
  height: 90px;
  animation: dragon .8s steps(2) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dragon {
  from {
   width: 93px;
    background-position: -7909px;
  }
  to {
   width: 113px;
    background-position: -8115px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="monster dragon"></div>

</body>
</html>
```